# navigating through a page with a login page in between

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a webpage using HTML, CSS & JS. In a section with a list of links, when a user clicks on any of the items in the list I want the user to first have to sign in before they continue on the path of the item they selected and I want to do this without having to duplicate a sign-in page for each stage. I want the link to first go to the login page(login.html) then continue or go back to the path it was on

the problem now is I don't know how exactly I can achieve this without creating multiple copies of the login page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must persist user state somewhere, either in browser (not safe at all) or on server.

- *In server*: Save information to cookie/session
- *In browser*: Save information to session/local storage

On every protected page visit check if user has been authorized by checking previously set flag. If it's not authorized, then redirect to login page. After successful authorization redirect back to requested protected page.

Comment: please can you explain in a simpler terms as i am still relatively new in javascript + i am ready to learn any topic that will help me solve this problem

Comment: @ife That would be too big to explain here. Please read about all these things yourself. Answer yourself where you will store users information, how they put that information to your system (as before login you must register), if setting up back-end server, then what language it will be, what OS it will use, what framework will be used, write down step-by-step all possible user actions to reach protected page.